# Can we change the values of the parameters defined in protractor configuration file in run time

Tags: javascript, protractor, configuration-files, parameters

I am trying to edit values which are defined in the conf.js file of protractor e2e testing.

```
params: {
        blnFlag: 'False'
    },
```

I am able to access the values in the below fashion

```
......
 console.log(browser.params.blnFlag);
 browser.params.blnFlag ='True';
......
```

False is being returned in console and when I try to change the value of blnFlag to True. The value is being changed when the scope is confined to the current js file only. Is it really possible to view the changes made in runtime when we use this global param in another js file?

Can some one help me with an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That is weird, what version of protractor do you have?

because it works fine for me:

```
var params = browser.params;
console.log(params.users.admin_user);
params.users.admin_user = 'test of params';
console.log(params.users.admin_user);
```

outputs:

```
{ user_name: 'ADMIN-USER', id: 2 }
test of params
```

(Params):

```
params: {
    users: {
        admin_user: {
            user_name: 'ADMIN-USER',
            id: 2
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I want to edit the value of params and hold it for future use. Is it really possible to use them in different js file?

Comment: So you basically want to edit params in protractor.conf.js and save it there for next test run?

Comment: Not for the next test run. In the current run itself I want to ensure whether what ever the value I am updating is being applied. Say: blnFlag is a param where it holds False as value and after performing some operations I want it to be True and I want to continue with the execution with blnFlag as True

Comment: Well that is exactly what this code does for me as seen in outputs.

And about the usage in different file. - browser.params are part of browser, so every part of your test that runs in single browser, will have the same params. 

So if you are not using `'shardTestFile: true` , or Multicapabilities, yes it will work everywhere.